# Setting HtmlAgilityPack to work with Mono for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, html-agility-pack

I've asked a similar question before, but nobody answered. How do I set `HtmlAgilityPack` to work with Mono for Android? I've added reference to `.dll` but when trying to use `HtmlDocument` I get error that

> System.Xml version 2.0.0.0 or 4.0.0.0 is missing.

But there is a default reference to System.Xml version 2.0.5.0. And if I reference 4.0.0.0 it works, but then some of the Mono for Android things don't work.
A user here gave me an Android specific version, but it seems that it doesn't contain `HtmlWeb`, which means it's useless.
How do I set `HtmlAgilityPack` to work with Mono for Android?

Comment: You have to compile it from source to target Mono for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [rebuild the HtmlAgilityPack source against the Mono for Android assemblies](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/2139/#Comment_2139).